# How to clear output of a terminal using seq_file interface?

Tags: c, linux, module

In linux user space program, the following code `printf("\033[2J\033[1;H");` clear output of a terminal.

I am wondering how to clear output of terminal in **linux kernel module programming?**

Is is possible using seq_file interface? Then, what should I do?

Comment: **What terminal?** The kernel only provides the [pseudoterminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) interface between the terminal emulator (`xterm` or similar) and the application(s) running in that terminal; it does not control the contents. Most Linux systems do support one or more serial, text mode, or framebuffer [consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console); you can access their contents via the `/dev/vcs` and/or `/dev/vcsa` devices (see eg. kernel [tty/vt/vt.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c)).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thank you for your comment. tty/vt/vc_screen.c will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That function can be applied to seq_file.

I mean, `seq_printf(m, "\033[2J\033[1;H");`